# How can I calculate covariance matrix from a random vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance

Given a random vector, `Y=[y1,y2,...,yn];`, its covariance matrix looks like this:

[image]

How can I calculate the covariance matrix in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

the covariance matrix can be computed with the `cov()` function. But be aware: the covariance matrix of a vector will always be a 1-by-1 matrix, because there are no cross-variances in a single variable.

```
% random vector of length 10
vec = rand(10,1);

% covariance matrix
cov(vec)
```